# Rails / JS - G+ signin button only works after page reload in some cases

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-oauth, turbolinks

I have a Rails app where users can sign in / up using Google SSO. I use the gem `omniauth-google-oauth2` and `One-time Code Flow (Hybrid Authentication)`. It work in some cases - but not all. It always works when I do a hard refresh of the page / browser.

The pattern I've noticed is that when I see this line in Chrome's JS console it works:

```
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:3000/signin
```

When `Navigated to [..]` isn't displayed it doesn't work. My suspicion is that it has something do do with either `turbo links` or some other caching issue.

I have tried the following to see if it was related to `turbo links`, but it didn't help:

```
# Coffeescript file
ready = -> 
  # Google logic and functions

$(document).ready(ready)
```

Any ideas on what can be causing this issue and how I can solve it?

Comment: You're probably correct regarding turbolinks but to test that I think you'll want `$(document).on('page:load', ready);` after your `$(document).ready(ready)`

Comment: Thanks @Exupery, the issue I see when I add `$(document).on('page:load', ready);` is that that code inside the `ready = ->` function gets called twice. And it didn't seem to help with my core issue - that the Google SSO doesn't work in all cases for me.

Comment: @Exupery Minor correction to my previous comment, it doesn't always run twice, when it doesn't run twice it works. But when it runs twice it doesn't.

Comment: Not sure why it's getting called twice, I have multiple RoR apps that use that workaround and it only gets called once (just double checked one of them). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18770589/903163) and its comments (which explain why it should never result in calling `ready` twice).

Comment: @Exupery Thanks again. Think I have solved it, and also possibly found the reason for the "double calls". Added it as an answer below. You can maybe take a look at it in action here (if you want :), https://www.brightly.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I solved it. In my `application.js` file I had both `//= require turbo links` and:

```
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

Removing `//= require turbo links` seems to have helped.